# vscode auto import, suggestion problem in Angular 7

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular7

**vscode** auto import and suggestion worked just fine with **angular 6**. but ever since I had upgraded to **Angular 7** it didn't work. It seems to me that vscode can't import from **node modules**. I was trying to import module but no suggestion came from vscode. For example, it can't even suggest and import **FormsModule**. What can I do to overcome this issue ?

Vscode Version: 1.33.1
Node.js: 10.2.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 6.3.9600

Package Version

@angular-devkit/architect 0.13.8 
@angular-devkit/build-angular 0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer 0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack 0.13.8
@angular-devkit/core 7.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics 7.3.8
@angular/cdk 7.2.0
@angular/cli 7.3.8
@angular/http 6.1.10
@angular/material 7.2.0
@ngtools/webpack 7.3.8
@schematics/angular 7.3.8
@schematics/update 0.13.8
rxjs 6.3.3
typescript 3.2.4
webpack 4.29.0

Comment: same thing for angular 9. I didn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

Set:

`"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative"`

and it will start working.

Comment: In the Visual Studio Code Workspace Settings this is. In case someone wouldn't find it.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved my problem.
First I had to import any class/module from any folder in node modules in any file under my workspace. After that vscode automatically detect the other contents (class/module) of that folder under node modules in that workspace.

for example I manually imported MatCardModule from angular/material in one of my file under my workspace. From the next time, vscode detected MatButtonsModule and others in that folder in every file of my workspace.

Thanks for patience